# SSL HandShake Exception:No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate);

Tags: java, docker, ssl

I am connecting email using imap

```
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(server, username, password);
```

The code is working fine and email is connected while running the project inlocal

But if we run the project in docker container. Below error is thrown.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate);
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665)
```

Docker File

```
FROM markhobson/maven-chrome:latest

WORKDIR /app

ARG ENVUrl=''

ENV ENVUrl $ENVUrl

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2"

COPY ./Framework .
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue. It's due to java version you are using in docker. If your are using java version 8u291 or later TLS V1.0,1.1 may be disabled. Please check the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742776/docker-container-javax-mail-messagingexception-no-appropriate-protocol-protoco) here

Answer (score -1):

Check your IMAP server's supported TLS protocol and cipher

Comment: How to validate whether the server supports  TLS Protocol and cipher .

Comment: Better to ask System Admin of that Server .. I have no idea to finding it out other way